# How to open FB send button popup top of the button position

Tags: facebook, interface

I am working on FB send and like button integration. But facing some problem as my buttons are set at the bottom of the page.

So when clicking of send button the flyout pop up opens beyond the visible area of the page.

Do anyone can help me in this issue.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Facebook Like Widget on Fan page, Comment area out of visible area](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808240/facebook-like-widget-on-fan-page-comment-area-out-of-visible-area)

Answer (score 1):

see [Facebook Like Widget on Fan page, Comment area out of visible area](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808240/facebook-like-widget-on-fan-page-comment-area-out-of-visible-area)

Answer (score 0):

This *[Facebook Send Button Flyout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340230/facebook-send-button-flyout)* will also help. It explains in more detail how to accomplish this. However it would be nice if this were an attribute that could be added to the send button.

Answer (score 0):

You can *hide* the flyover by using overflow:hidden in your container.